# set_error_handler() receives invalid callback?

Tags: php, error-handling, callback

I receive this error:

> set_error_handler() expects the argument (userErrorAdvice) to be a valid callback

---

```
trait userErrorAdviceTrait
{
    public function userErrorAdvice()
    {
        $error = error_get_last();
        $_SESSION['errorStore'] = $error;
        $errorMessage = "No file exists for the PageController";
        if (strstr($error['message'], "No file exists for the PageController class"))
        {
            header('Location: http://192.171.127.39/~louis/errorAdvicePage.php?errorType=NoPageControllerError');
            exit;
        }
    }
    public function setUserErrorAdvice()
    {
        set_error_handler("userErrorAdvice");
    }
}
```

---

```
use userErrorAdviceTrait;
public static function makePageController($pageName) 
{
    //self::shutDownFunction();
    //self::shutdown_function();
    self::setUserErrorAdvice();

    //Rest of code ....
```

This is forcing me to write more details but i have nothing left to say.

Comment: Not 100% sure on this, but I'm guessing it's a scope issue. `set_error_handler` is not just for within a specific class, but your entire script, so it is looking for a global function called `userErrorAdvice()`. Since it doesn't find that it throws that error.

Comment: `http://192.171.127./~louis[etc]` doesn't look like a valid URL.

Comment: nvm the url that's just an error in how i typed it on stackoveflow. Will adjust.

Comment: @Flaco_Taco in regard to your last edit, no, this is not "forcing" you to add any details. If the question feels empty, it's because it is. Don't add fluff to add fluff, it's the reason I removed it at first.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple working test for this. Here is the code I'm going to review

```
<?php

trait userErrorAdviceTrait
{
    public function function userErrorAdvice($errno, $errstr)
    {
        echo 'error no '.$errno.' and message '.$errstr.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function setUserErrorAdvice()
    {
        set_error_handler("userErrorAdvice");
    }
}

class TestErrorFunction
{
    use userErrorAdviceTrait;

    public static function makePageController($pageName)
    {
        self::setUserErrorAdvice();
    }
}

TestErrorFunction::makePageController('page');
```

I see some issues here. Let me explain and fix them.

1. You use non static functions as static. When the method (function) `userErrorAdvice()` should be executed it should 'have' and object. But no object is created for the function.
2. The argument for the [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function should be [PHP callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). In our case there is no global function `userErrorAdvice()`.

There are several possible options to fix the issues. For example

```
<?php

trait userErrorAdviceTrait
{
    public static function userErrorAdvice($errno, $errstr )
    {
        echo 'error no '.$errno.' and message '.$errstr.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function setUserErrorAdvice()
    {
        set_error_handler([userErrorAdviceTrait::class, "userErrorAdvice"]);
        // the other option here
        // set_error_handler('userErrorAdviceTrait::userErrorAdvice');
    }
}

class TestErrorFunction
{
    use userErrorAdviceTrait;

    public static function makePageController($pageName)
    {
        self::setUserErrorAdvice();
        include 'no existing file';
    }
}

TestErrorFunction::makePageController('page');
```

This code produced the following output.

```
$ php code.php 
error no 2 and message include(no existing file): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
error no 2 and message include(): Failed opening 'no existing file' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')
```

One more time what have I done

1. Fixed callable parameter.
2. Defined methods as static cause they are used in static context.